# How to search and replace specific character strings in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file where something went wrong with the encoding of the "ß" character.
Its a street data set and every street looks like the following `"UsastraÃ?e"` or `"Example StraÃ?e"`
well i thought no problem lets use R like a text editor and run the following command:

```
gsub("Ãƒ?", "ß", dataColumn)
```

but it returns the following wrong output.
`Usastraß?e` and `Example Straß?e` so the ? is still there and i cant remove it with an additional gsub command like `gsub("?", "", dataColumn)`

Using the following code:

```
gsub("Ã?", "ß", dataColumn)
```

this completely deletes the column.

When using the `view()` command `ß` is displayed as `Stra�?e`
using the command:

```
gsub("�?e", "ß", dataColumn)
```

produces the wrong output
`UsastraÃ?ß` and `Example StraÃ?ß`

I also tried similar things with the `readLines()` command thinking in plain text would work.

So my question is is there a solution to my problem writing an clean `ß` back into a file. Like doing a search and replace command in and Text Editor.

Comment: The question mark is a special character in regular expressions. Try `gsub("Ãƒ?", "ß", dataColumn, fixed=TRUE)` to cancel the special treatment. If those three characters should all be changed regardless of order use `gsub("[Ãƒ?]", "ß", dataColumn)`.

Comment: Instead of `fixed = TRUE`, you can also escape the literal `?` with a double backslash. `gsub('Ã\\?', 'ß', 'UsastraÃ?e')` returns `"Usastraße"`.